# How to change a method in DOM objects prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I want to change `open()` method in `XMLHttpRequest` objects. actually I need to change every url that will send trough xhr. how can I do this?

for example when xhr objects open one request for `http://domain.com/` I want to change it to `https://domain.com/`

Comment: I wouldn't advise that you actually change the default method. Just create your own function that returns XHR objects made to your liking.

Comment: This may be possible, but either way it is terrible practice to alter the prototype of native constructors, even more existing ones. What if you or a future extension ever need to make a request with the `http` protocol? It will be broken and fixing it will then break the rest of your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can intrupt any method on native DOM objects but that is not recommnended. Don't do this.

Anyway if you want to know how to manipulate `XMLXttpRequest`'s `open` method, this is how you do it:

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(){ 
   // do stuff you want 
   // for example console.log:
   console.log('test');
   // then let open method happen
   open.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

For your very use case that is changing `protocol` of URL, you can do this:

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(){ 
   var link = document.createElement('a'); // make an anchar element
   link.href = arguments[1]; // make it's href equal to second argument which is URL
   link.protocol = 'https:'; // force https to the link
   arguments[1] = link.href; // write back URL form link that is now start with 'https'
   // then let open method happen
   open.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: dear mohesen I have a question and hope you can answer me :X

Comment: how I can trap all http requests by javascript? I need to change all of them